How do I perform new work on a file already in an unmerged GitHub PR?
To start, I'm still a git noob... I know my way around with basic commands to get and manage content, open PR's, etc. We have a single .yaml file that we maintain for all of our API operations in our "development" repo. (I know, I know... not ideal.) I recently created a branch ("my-work-branch"), made several updates to the file, and committed them to a PR in GitHub. That PR is waiting to be merged because approvals are required. Now, I've been tasked with adding new operations to the file. So, I run git status and it shows:
"On branch my-work-branch
nothing to commit, working tree clean"
...as expected, right? So, I tried to create a new branch for the work ("my-new-work-branch"), and of course the changes are still showing in the diff in VS Code, because it's the same file and that PR hasn't been merged. I'm worried about a merge conflict, if I start working in this new branch. I did some Googling and found "git stash." But it looks like that's not an option because I've already committed the initial changes in a PR. Any suggestions on what I can do? Do I need to just wait 'til the PR gets merged?
Before you jump in and give solutions like, "Break down your API into multiple .yaml files, instead of a single one," I don't have any control over this. It is what it is.
Thanks in advance.

For those who may have the same issue, the only solution I could find was to:

Create a new branch and check out that branch.
Start working on the updates.
When the PR for the original work -- on the other branch -- is finally approved, git stash all of the update work.
Switch to the original branch and merge the PR.
Switch back to the new branch and git fetch/git pull to sync your local content.
Run git stash to get your update content back.


Yeah... I'm that guy: over-commenting on my own string. Sharing this to hopefully help anyone else who may have this issue: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/21765.
Simply put, always go back to your main branch and reference that main branch, when creating a new branch... in my case, that's the "development" branch. That way, your new branch doesn't reference changes in your other commit. (Essentially, branch from the "trunk," not another branch.) When you merge all your commits, pull from your main branch to sync your local repo, to get the updates.
